# Can't show included CSS and JS on subpages

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, realurl

On subpages, for example `mysite.com/about/`, CSS and JS are not working.

From page source:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="typo3conf/ext/news/Resources/Public/Css/news.css" media="all">
```

When I click the CSS link, it leads to

```
mysite.com/about/typo3conf/.../news.css
```

instead of

```
mysite.com/typo3conf/.../news.css
```

Using currently latest versions of:

- realURL
- t3sbootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As realurl simulates a subdirectory, the pathes to the CSS and JS files, which are relative to webroot, are wrong.
You either have to use

```
config.baseURL = /
```

or (preferrable) use

```
config.absRefPrefix = /
```